# Testing types with issubclass returns inconsistent results

Tags: python, pytest, python-typing

I have a `class A` with no attributes, which I test to see if it is a subclass of `typing.Container`.  That test fails, as expected.

In a separate test I add the `__contains(self, k)__` attribute to A, and test to see if it is a subclass of `typing.Container`, and that test passes.

Now the weird thing is if I test whether `A` is a subclass of `typing.Conainer`, and then add the `__contains(self, k)__` attribute, and then again test whether `A` is a subclass of `typing.Container`, that test fails.

What is happening that causes the last test to fail, even when `A` does have the attribute `__contains__(self, k)__`?

```py
import pytest
from typing import Container

@pytest.fixture
def A():
    class A:...
    return A

def test_notsubclass(A):
    # passes
    assert not issubclass(A, Container)

def test_addcontains(A):
    # passes
    def __contains__(self, k): ...
    setattr(A, '__contains__', __contains__)
    assert issubclass(A, Container)

def test_first_then_add_contains(A):
    # passes
    assert not issubclass(A, Container)
    def __contains__(self, k): ...
    setattr(A, '__contains__', __contains__)

    # fails
    assert issubclass(A, Container)
```

Comment: The only think I can think of is that `issubclass` does some sort of memoization and doesn't actually perform a full check the second time `issubclass` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime representations of many `typing` types are wrappers around the corresposding `collections.abc` type. [For example, `typing.Container` is a generic "alias" of `collections.abc.Container`:](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/302df02789d041a09760f86295ea6b4dcd81aa1d/Lib/typing.py#L1660)

```
Container = _alias(collections.abc.Container, 1)
```

As the name implies, `collections.abc` members derive from `abc.ABC`/`abc.ABCMeta`. Since ABC subclass/instance checking can be expensive, [`abc.ABCMeta` has an optimisation to cache subclass checks](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/302df02789d041a09760f86295ea6b4dcd81aa1d/Lib/_py_abc.py#L87-L147).